# Extend webdriver.WebDriver functions

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to extend selenium `webdriver.WebDriver`, functions to enable me to log output from a command, for example

```
WebdriverReporter.prototype.sendKeys = function(keys){
 //call original method + call my api to store the keys
}
```

I am trying to make my webdriverreporter inherit from the webdriver however I am struggling to create a new instance of webdriver.

code:

```js
var util = require('util');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');


var WebdriverReporter = function(){
  webdriver.WebDriver.apply(this);
  console.log("constructor: webdriver reporter");
};

util.inherits(WebdriverReporter, webdriver.WebDriver);

var a = new WebdriverReporter();

console.log("test", a instanceof webdriver.WebDriver);
```

error:

```js
constructor(session, executor, opt_flow) {
             ^

TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I usually create a new webdriver using:

```js
new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser(config.browser.chrome.browserName)
    .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
    .build();
```

however it will not work in this new instance

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in this line -

```
webdriver.WebDriver.apply(this);
```

Try  -

```
webdriver.WebDriver.call(this);
```

See -

[Node.JS Docs - util.inherits](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)

[MDN - Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript - Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance)

Comment: If that doesn't work you may have to set the prototype yourself using webdriver.Builder()

Comment: it appears that when I use call, it asks me to make a new instance similar to the error above, however when I create a new instance of webdriver, the driver itself has no prototype